# Irreducible polynomials in two and four variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I am trying to show that the polynomials :

1) $X^2+Y^2-1$

2) $XT-YZ$

are irreducible in $\mathbb Q[X,Y]$ and $\mathbb Q[X,Y,Z,T]$ respectively.

For 1) I know that $\mathbb  Q[X,Y]=(\mathbb Q[X])[Y]$ and $X^2+Y^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)+Y^2$ but this didn't help me, I would appreciate any hints or suggestions for both polynomials. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work for #1: Look at $f(X,Y) = X^{2}+Y^{2}-1$ as a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Q}[X])[Y]$. Then as you noted, $f(X,Y) = Y^{2} + (X-1)(X+1)$. Applying Eisenstein's criterion to the prime ideal $(X-1)$ shows $f(X,Y)$ is irreducible in $(\mathbb{Q}[X])[Y]$, hence is irreducible $\mathbb{Q}[X,Y]$.

As observed in the comments by the OP, one can view $f(X,Y, Z,T) = XT-YZ$ as a polynomial in $(\mathbb{Q}[X, Y, Z])[T]$, whence we apply Eisenstein's criterion to the prime ideal $(Z)$ in $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y, Z]$, which shows the desired conclusion.

Comment: for the second problem can you please explain the mapping in detail.I am not getting it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In 2) I've been trying to show that the function you've defined is a morphism and that the kernel is $<XT-YZ>$ but I couldn't. Couldn't we apply Eisenstein's criterion just as in 1)? I mean, $\mathbb Q[X,Y,Z,T]=(\mathbb Q[X,Y,Z])[T]$, so if I could show that $YZ$ is a prime in $\mathbb Q[X,Y,Z]$, then I will be able to apply the criterion. Could you help me to show $YZ$ is indeed a prime?

Comment: @user16924: no problem! Indeed, I think my answer to #2 might be much harder to prove than I thought. I'll see if I can't show it some other way (perhaps by showing that $YZ$ is prime), and edit the answer if I'm able to figure it out.

Comment: @user16924: Unfortunately, I don't think $YZ$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Q}[X, Y, Z]$. Note that if we put $f=Y, g=Z$, then $fg \in (YZ)$ but neither $f$ nor $g$ is in $(YZ)$. I think we must take another strategy, although some kind of modified argument of this kind may work.

Comment: You're right, what if we take $Z$?

Comment: @user16924: Good thinking! $(Z)$ is certainly a prime ideal, but $YZ \notin (Z^{2})$. I think that should work! I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

For 1st problem ,I have tried something check whether it works or not

Writing the polynomial as a product of two 1 degree polynomials in $x$ and $y$(which has to be the case in order for the polynomial to be reducible)

$x^2+y^2-1=(a_1x+b_1y+c_1)(a_2x+b_2y+c_2)$

Expanding the product on the R.H.S. we have $a_1a_2=1;b_1b_2=1;a_1b_2+b_1a_2=0$

which is not possible as $a_1$and $a_2$ must be of same sign ;$b_1$and $b_2$ must be of same sign for two equations to hold which clearly contradicts the 3rd equation .Thus polynomial not reducible

Please comment on whether this technique works